# Repeated call of copy constructor for same pointer-variable a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, deep-copy

I have a small question:

```
Foo *myFoo;
myFoo = new Foo(anotherFoo);     // some deep copy of another object
myFoo = new Foo(yetAnotherFoo);  // another deep copy of yet another object
```

Is this a memory leak and if yes, how can I avoid it properly? The situation in my program is, that 'myFoo' is a class member and I want to use it as a "one and only" storage-object for a deep copy of some other object from time to time (because the copied object is modified afterwards and I need the initial object for later comparison).

I have tried a simple workaround like:

```
// within a class method of the same class
if (myFoo!=NULL) delete myFoo;
myFoo = new Foo(fooToStore);
```

but this crashes my program as soon as the destructor is called. I am not sure if my (non-trivial) destructor is a bit buggy (different problem not to discuss here) or if deleting a class-member object via delete within a class method is forbidden in general.

Thanks a lot for your time and help - appreciate it!
Mark

Comment: Sidenote: there is no need to check if myFoo is NULL before calling delete, delete handles NULL values correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a memory leak, because the second assignment to `myFoo` causes the first `Foo` you allocated to become inaccessible. Deleting `myFoo` between successive allocations is the correct thing to do. Note that you don't need to check for a null pointer: `delete` takes care of that. It looks very likely that you have some problem in `Foo`'s destructor.

Comment: ... and may be even constructor, if the destructor does a delete of an uninitialized member pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will have a closer look at both the constructor and destructor. Regards, Mark

Answer (score 4):

Not deleting the result of a `new` expression before re-assigning the pointer surely causes a memory leak. The explicit-`delete` solution should work, but what you really want is a smart pointer-typed member, e.g. a [`scoped_ptr<Foo>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm).

That might (or might not) magically solve your destructor problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "but this crashes my program as soon as the destructor is called" means that main class destructor invoke 'myFoo'delete.

Don't forget to initialize 'myFoo' to null in main class constructor, this will prevent crashes on main class destructor if no instances of 'myFoo' are created.